# error when i run "pip install chatterbot"

Tags: chatterbot

when i run the comman `pip install chatterbot` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work too

````
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apehx1f6\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (75 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.3.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached wasabi-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.2.tar.gz (192 kB)
  Processing c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\a3\17\dd\f2dba23a35bb6008732772ccfb13d3d0e537fbc6919ce6862b\numpy-1.19.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.50.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for cymem, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for preshed, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for murmurhash, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for thinc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for blis, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for srsly, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for cymem: started
      Running setup.py install for cymem: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sebas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-px5vncs8\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sebas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-px5vncs8\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1249wihi\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apehx1f6\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apehx1f6\overlay\Include\cymem'
           cwd: C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-px5vncs8\cymem\
      Complete output (35 lines):
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
      copying cymem\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
      copying cymem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
      package init file 'cymem\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem\tests
      copying cymem\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem\tests
      copying cymem\cymem.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
      copying cymem\cymem.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
      copying cymem\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cymem
      running build_ext
      building 'cymem.cymem' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cymem
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt /EHsc /Tpcymem/cymem.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cymem/cymem.obj /Ox /EHsc
      cymem.cpp
      cymem/cymem.cpp(4501): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      cymem/cymem.cpp(4509): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      cymem/cymem.cpp(4519): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      cymem/cymem.cpp(4525): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
      c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
      cymem/cymem.cpp(4969): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
      c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(446): note: see declaration of '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length'
      cymem/cymem.cpp(4985): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
      c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(446): note: see declaration of '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sebas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-px5vncs8\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sebas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-px5vncs8\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1249wihi\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apehx1f6\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apehx1f6\overlay\Include\cymem' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\sebas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Sebas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-apehx1f6\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.```

IGNORE THIS BELOW
when i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work toowhen i run the comman ```pip install chatterbot``` i got this issue and dont install :c i try adding the building tools and visual c++ 14.0 and didn work too
````

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to Python 3.8 - it's too soon for Python 3.9 (for chatterbox).