# Win10 Python 3.8.1 64bit failing Installing spaCy's build dependencies

Tags: pip, spacy, python-3.8, failed-installation, chatterbot

### Summary

When I'm trying to intall a python module 'ChatterBot' (tried diffrent versions (from 1.0.4 to 1.0.8), on some - needs python 3.4), it starts collecting 'spaCy' (v2.1.9), and then i'm get this error:

### Error

```
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\пка12345\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\пка12345\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\пка12345\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gfehcqzq\overlay' --no-warn-script-location -v --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

[(logs)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o829tdvh7FKPvtCX2k3Ayom-bE0UP6y1/view?usp=sharing)

### Tried to do

1. Install chatterbot via git (newest version)|Result: it needs python 3.4, but I'm have python 3.8.1
2. Install spaCy separatly |Result: It downloades newest version that bot works with chatteerbot
3. Try installing different versions  of chatterbot| Result: The same error on half of the versions, other half needs python3.4 but I'm have python 3.8.1

Comment: `pip install chatterbot` worked for me, but I have Python 3.7 (*Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32*) and I have already had SpaCy installed. Make sure you run `cmd` as an admin.

Comment: Yes, I'm running cmd as an admin

Comment: Can confirm the issue is due to deprecations in python 3.8+. Use Python 3.7 or below.

Also possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286366/error-when-i-run-pip-install-chatterbot)

Comment: Found [this Github issue](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1854), see [suggested workaround](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1854#issuecomment-549384203) that implies installing Python 3.7